# TFS 2010 Changeset remains as pending even after merge

Tags: tfs, changeset

I have a TPC with with a project with multiple sub-branches

Collection
  - Project A
    - Development Branch
      - App 1
      - App 2
      - App 3
    - QA Branch
      - App 1
      - App 2
      - App 3
    - Root Branch
      - App 1
      - App 2
      - App 3
  - Project B...

My issue seems to be even after merging a changeset from Development --> QA or QA --> Development some changesets are now showing as pending in the target branch

Example: I merge file "Customer.cs" from QA branch to Development branch. I then get into the GUI and look at the pending changeset between Development and QA and I see the changeset I just merged from QA, same comment etc.

This does not happen with every changeset, but I have at least 4 changeset I cannot seem to clear up. I have tried using the GUI to merge and the tf merge -r -discard -version:Cxxx~Cxxx -comment:"some comment" $/Source $/Target 
but still unable to resolve.

Ideas?

Comment: When you say you merged on the command line what commands did you run exactly?  Did your `tf checkin` fail to match the item spec that has the pending merge?

Answer (score 0):

The changeset which you merged from Dev -> QA, does it have only the one file "Customer.cs"? I assume the changeset has multiple files within and thats why its still showing.